# How to realize that?

Tags: flutter, dart, text, richtext

I see there ListView, that has a `TrackWidget`.

TrackWidget contains a Row, that has Text(number), Text(title), Text(subtitle), Text(time) and Button.

[image]

**But,** there may also be title that is larger than Row size. In this case, Text(title) should take all the place.

[image]

**Help me, please.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `RichText` Widget might be the way to go, using it the text rendered in priority would be the first one so the song title in your case.

Also don't forget to set `TextOverflow.ellipsis` to have the `...` when text is too long.

**Example**

```dart
ListTile(
  leading: Text(songTrackNumber, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)),
  title: RichText(
    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
    text: TextSpan(
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      children: [
        TextSpan(text: songTitle),
        TextSpan(text: songAlbum, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)),
      ],
    ),
  ),
  trailing: Text(songLength, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)),
);
```

[Try full example on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/73349e21adb8be469facade4f03135a2)

Answer (score 0):

The `Text` widget looks like it's using a technique to create ellipses. Let's say you have the `Row` widget below:

```dart
Row(
  children: [
    Text('Row 1, Text 1', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, color: Colors.red)),

    SizedBox(width: 8),
    Text('Row 1, Text 2', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, color: Colors.orange)),

    SizedBox(width: 8),
    
    // This is the widget/text you want to change format. 
    Text('Row 1, Text 3', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, color: Colors.yellow)),

    SizedBox(width: 8),
    Text('Row 1, Text 4', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, color: Colors.green)),
  ],
);
```

You'll want to wrap that widget in a `Container`, then wrap the `Container` in a `Flexible` widget. Finally add an ellipsis overflow to the `Text` widget.

Like this:

```dart
Row(
  children: [
    Text('Row 1, Text 1', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, color: Colors.red)),
    SizedBox(width: 8),
    Text('Row 1, Text 2', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, color: Colors.orange)),
    SizedBox(width: 8),


    /// Our new updated widget.
    Flexible(
      child: Container(
        child: Text(
          'Row 1, Text 3',
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, color: Colors.yellow),
        ),
      ),
    ),


    SizedBox(width: 8),
    Text('Row 1, Text 4', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, color: Colors.green)),
    SizedBox(width: 8),
  ],
);
```

This is what it would look like:
[image: Full row]

Notice the the yellow text is now clipped.
[image: clipped text]

See the Dart Pad Demo [here](https://dartpad.dev/395c659d3be9ade5092b7cc109c8e987).

Comment: Unfortunately this did not solve my problem. The goal is to make the orange text so that the yellow text is not visually visible. (in cases when orange text is too large). Thx for your efforts. ^^